# second order systems undamped natural frequency

Tags: control-system, resonance

Hellow, 
I understand that every second order system has an Undamped Natural Frequency, i also understand that if i am vibrating the system (sin wave) in the same frequency i will have a response with a max amplitude. 
Does this true only for a system that has roots with complex numbers?

Comment: The oscillation is given by the `w^2` term, and it's expressed as: `w^2=re(s)^2+im(s)^2`, where `s` is the pole(/zero) and `re()` and `im()` denote the real and the imaginary parts of the pole/zero, respectively. Whichever part is zero, or not, it's all there.

Comment: Thanks, but if the system roots in the poles are real, can i have resonance effect? Or a resonance effect happens only when the roots are complex?

Answer (score 2):

The undamped natural frequency, \$\omega_n\$, of a second order system is determined from the denominator of the TF, written in the standard form: \$s^2+2\zeta \omega _ns+\omega^2 _n\$. The value of \$\zeta\$ is irrelevant, and the system could be heavily overdamped - the undamped natural frequency is that at which the system would resonate if the damping were reduced to zero.

If \$\zeta\$ is taken as zero, then the roots of the denominator will be purely imaginary: \$s^2+\omega^2_n=0\$; giving \$s=\pm j\omega_n\$

Maximum amplitude (resonance) will occur at \$\omega_n\$ only if \$\zeta=0\$. If \$\zeta\ne 0\$, resonance will occur at a frequency \$\omega_r \lt \omega_n\$, and \$\omega_r \$ generally decreases as \$\zeta\$ increases.

Comment: Thanks, but i am only asking about the frequency response.

Comment: It is about frequency response! A 2nd order resonance peak (i.e. a peak in the sinusoid amplitude) can only exist if the roots are complex or imaginary.